# Oracle 12c Installation Error: "Exception ... Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit"

Tags: java, oracle

I have been trying to install oracle 12 c on Ubuntu 14.10 but facing the below mentioned error.Could some one please check this and advise me how to fix this error?

```
Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 429214 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4041 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
    >>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n] Y


>>> Ignoring required pre-requisite failures. Continuing...
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2014-10-27_11-15-08PM. Please wait ...oracle@v3nky-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:834)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(LookUtils.java:484)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:249)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:135)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1852)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:557)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:792)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:198)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:355)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:130)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:161)
```

Comment: First observation: The installer seems to try to open a GUI and can't find a DISPLAY. Are you running this on a headless server? Is there a option to tell the installer to install without a display? If you connect with `ssh` you could add the option `-X` and use your local display. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for an update Mike..i am not installing it on server..i am doing it on my home laptop..

Comment: Could some one please help me on the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you. Still, adding more information might help others to find a solution. Please click [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/542485/edit) below your question: Do you follow a tutorial? On which step did this error happen? Was there anything else didn't quite work?

Answer (score 7):

Check if some JDK is installed in your system:

```
$ java -version
```

Installing JDK 7 solved my problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

If the problem persists, log as root, then execute:

```
$ xhost +
```

Switch back to another user and run installation again.

Answer (score 3):

I had this as well. As root, I executed `xhost +` first and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Solution, copy the file:

```
cp /root/.Xauthority /home/grid/.Xauthority
```

Insure that the user can read & write to the file by:

```
chmod 600 /home/grid/.Xauthority
chown grid /home/grid/.Xauthority
```